# Remove dots after numbers in "disser" template

Tags: table-of-contents

How i shoud change the code, if i want to remove dots after numbers in table of contents?
I'm using LaTeX with Russian "disser" template with my own editions, so many of examples form internet are did not worked.

Now i have:

```
1. Test
   1.1. Test
2. Test
```

But i need:

```
1 Test
  1.1 Test
2 Test
```

How i can perform this?

My code example:

```
\documentclass[14pt, specialist, natbib, subf, href, colorlinks=true, numbers=noenddot]{disser}
\usepackage[a4paper, mag=1000, left=3cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.7cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Тест 1}
    \subsection{Тест 1.1}
    \section{Тест 2}
    \section{Тест 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example minimal.

Comment: Does `\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{}` work?

Comment: I'm afraid no, i can't see difference with `\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{}`

Comment: It was just a try. What does the `numbers=noenddot` as option do?

Comment: @TeXnician, Oh, this is rudimentary code from the times, when i'm tried to remove dots after sections, thank you for reminding me to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dots are inserted by `\tocpostthesection` etc. Its original definition is 
`\providecommand\tocpostthesection{.\@postskip}`. So you have to redefine these commands to remove the dot.

```
\documentclass[14pt, specialist, natbib, subf, href, colorlinks=true]{disser}
\usepackage[a4paper, mag=1000, left=3cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.7cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocpostthepart{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocpostthechapter{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocpostthesection{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocpostthesubsection{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocpostthesubsubsection{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocposttheparagraph{\@postskip}
\renewcommand\tocpostthesubparagraph{\@postskip}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Тест часть}
\chapter{Тест глава}
\section{Тест 1}
\subsection{Тест 1.1}
\section{Тест 2}
\section{Тест 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]